# Has the behavior of numpy.random.randn() changed in any NumPy version?

Tags: numpy, random

I wonder whether the behavior of `numpy.random.randn()` has changed in any NumPy version. I have set a seed `np.random.seed(0)` to try to ensure reproducibility, but I wonder whether the NumPy version may impact the numbers returned by `numpy.random.randn()` as well.